# What's the word Germans give to walls that aren't well soundproofed?

Tags: translation

For example, I want to explain how I can hear what my neighbours are saying. So I would say my flat is ____________ ?

Comment: Just say anything. As long as you say it loudly enough, they'll get the message.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The appropriate adjective here is

> **hellhörig**

Which the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hellhoerig) describes as

> besonders von Räumen, Gebäuden o. Ä.) den Schall leicht durchlassend
>
> Beispiel
>   *eine hellhörige Wohnung*

-> Precisely the use case in your question.

Comment: Doesn't quite fit to *walls*, however. The original English sentence would need to be slightly rearranged

Comment: @tofro It fits the half sentence in the question body.

Comment: @tofro The expression hellhörige Wände does exist (at least in south Germany)

Comment: @tofro I opened this question to check if anyone had already answered "hellhörig", which **is** the correct answer (I'm a native German).

Comment: The title asks for the adjective to _walls_, while the example asks for the adjective to _flats_. For a flat, Stephie has the right answer: _hellhörig_. For walls, it is _schalldurchlässig_.

Comment: This is exaclty what I would say (as a native speaker).

Comment: Another German confirms.

Comment: The formally correct term for walls may well be *schalldurchlässig*, but if I complain about the walls to my friends, I'll also talk about *hellhörige Wände".

Comment: colloquially, I'd also say "dünne Wände"

Comment: In Berlin, and in the talk of estate agents here, I am acquainted with both "die Wohnung/das Zimmer hat hellhörige Wände" and "die **Wohnung** ist hellhörig", although the latter seems more common to me.

Comment: As a native speaker, I can say I have encountered "hellhörig" both for walls and for flats, and neither feels wrong or weird to me. Maybe it's a regional thing. For reference, I grew up in central Germany and live in the northwest now.

Answer (score 10):

not well soundproofed

... nicht gut schallisoliert.

Comment: That’s what I say.

Comment: Ok, ich schreibe immer alles klein auf facebook. Jetzt gebe ich mir Mühe, damit man versteht isoliert gegen Schall und nie ist es recht! 50 jahre haben wir schallisoliert klein und in einem Wort geschrieben, dann kommt der Duden mit der neuen Rechtschreibung und dreht  wieder alles um. Verkehrte Welt! Wir Eidgenossen haben unsere eigene Rechtschreibung. Es leben die Gemsen!

Comment: Was willst du denn, schallisoliert ist doch ok: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schallisoliert

Comment: Ich sags ja: der Duden!

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli die neue Rechtschreibung hat nie verlangt, Wörter wie schallisoliert getrennt zu schreiben. Dass man so etwas heutzutage so häufig sieht, liegt zum einen an der hohen Verbreitung von schlechter Software für Rechtschreibkontrolle, die mit zusammengesetzten Worten nicht klar kommt und laufend unnötige oder gar falsche Getrenntschreibung vorschlägt. Zum anderen liegt es an falschem Verständnis, wie eben Deinem, das der neuen Rechtschreibung Dinge unterstellt, die gar nicht da sind. Und dann ist der Duden schuld, wenn Du diese nicht-existenten Regeln umsetzt.

Comment: Danke, Holger, war nicht bös gemeint ;)
50 jahre schallisorliert war doch falsch, oder? als ich jung war, galt die regel für fast alle adverben und adjektive: kleinundzusammen!

Comment: While that word certainly is correct, I feel it's worth pointing out that it is a very technical term: it may appear in a formal complaint to your landlord or their response, or in contexts like scientific studies, lawsuits and the like. However, encountering it in everyday communication would feel weird / foreign / stiff to me (native speaker from central Germany living in the northwest).

Answer (score 10):

Also, you commonly hear "Dieses Haus hat dünne Wände" - "This house has thin walls", regardless of how whether the walls are physically thin.

Answer (score 5):

## Pappwände

> Meine Wohnung hat **Pappwände**, ich kann alles hören, was meine Nachbarn machen.

Describing as the name implies that the walls are paper thin and not really blocking the sound.